# Why doesn't SwiftUI's Kingfisher KFImage.Placeholder(UIImage(named: "logo")) accept UIImage as acceptable?

Tags: image, swiftui, kingfisher

I add the following code to a VStack in SwiftUI:

```
KFImage.url(url)
     .placeholder(UIImage(named: "logo"))
     .setProcessor(processor)
     .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
```

But XCode doesn't like it and says "Cannot convert value of type UIImage? to expected argument type '() -> Content'"

Kingfisher's cheatsheet indicates that the placeholder line should work:

```
.placeholder(UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

When I remove the placeholder line (line2 above), it works properly.  But, of course, there is no placeholder.

Using SwiftUI, how can I set the placeholder for KFImage?

I've only been coding with Swift/SwiftUI for a month now so I'm quite new.

Thankyou.

Swift Version 5.0
Kingfisher Version 6.1.0

Comment: Maybe you need to import UIKit in this file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error that you are getting is telling that `placeholder` wants a SwiftUI View (eg `() -> Content`) and you're trying to provide it a `UIKit` UIImage instead.

Instead, you should give it a SwiftUI `Image`.

You could easily initialize `Image` with a `UIImage`, but keep in mind that `UIImage(named:)` returns an Optional (which your error hinted at as well), so if you want to use it without checking it for `nil` first, you'll need to force unwrap it:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "logo")!)
```

Even better, just initialize your SwiftUI `Image` with the name and skip `UIImage` altogether unless you need it for some other reason:

```
Image("logo")
```

```
.placeholder { Image("logo") }
```

Comment: Thankyou.  That helped me solve the problem!  It still wasn't working though, and it only started working when I used .placeholder { Image("logo") } instead of parenthesis.
As in XCode still said Image wasn't acceptable until I used curly brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: Nice -- I've edited my answer to reflect that in case others come in the future to see it. Since I see you're new here, please feel free to now upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Goodo.  Yeah I did upvote it, but I don't have enough reputation for my vote to be publicly displayed.  It's a thumbs up from me anyway.